# Pass PHP serialize value to swift

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I'm trying to pass PHP serialize value from WordPress WP-postmeta to Swift and unserialize it and other way around.
Here's a example of PHP serialize:

s:21:"a:1:{i:276;s:2:"on";}";

So I was wondering if Swift can handle this or should I unserialize it in PHP and then pass it to Swift?
I tried to unserialize it from PHP but I got error, it would be great if someone show me how to unserialize my sample PHP serialize.

```
$a = s:21:"a:1:{i:276;s:2:"on";}";  
print_r(unserialize($a));
```

Comment: Can't you unserialize in PHP and pass it as (say) JSON?

Comment: I know PHP has unserialize() function but I got error when I passed the serialized value into it.

Comment: Definitely unserialize in PHP first, then pass the value to Swift.  I wouldn't want to rely on one language knowing about the internals of another.  Your code has two problems.  First, you need quotes around your declaration of `$a` (single ones, since the value contains double ones): `$a = 's:21:"a:1:{i:276;s:2:"on";}";';`.  Second, the value has been serialized twice, though I don't know why. `print_r(unserialize(unserialize($a)));` will probably do what you're expecting.

Comment: That was great :-) Thank you so much! @Hobo